# Mongodb QueryByExample findOne

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, query-by-example

Some other process  inserts documents  into mongo collection and below is the sample data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("597b89c8da52380b04ee6948"), "_class" : "com.test.mongo", "clientId" : "CAQ123999", "isValid" : false, "isParent" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("597b89c8da52380b04ee6949"), "_class" : "com.test.mongo", "clientId" : "CAQ123999", "isValid" : false, "isParent" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("597b89c8da52380b04ee6950"), "_class" : "com.test.mongo", "clientId" : "CAQ123998", "isValid" : true, "isParent" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("597b89c8da52380b04ee6951"), "_class" : "com.test.mongo", "clientId" : "CAQ123997", "isValid" : true, "isParent" : false }
```

I'm trying to grab one record for the clientId, using QueryByExampleExecutor.

Here is my model

```
package com.test.cfp.model;
public class TFSModel {

    private String clientId;
    private boolean isValid;
    private boolean isParent;
    ...

}
```

**Here is the code to build the example:**

```
TFSModel tfs = new TFSModel();
            tfs.setClientId(CAQ123999);
            tfs.setValid(false);
            tfs.setParent(true);    
            ExampleMatcher matcher =ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreNullValues().withIgnorePaths("_id","_class");
            Example<TFSModel > example = Example.of(tfs,matcher);           
            TFSModel oneTfsRecord  = tflsRepository.findOne(example);
```

This is not working , below is the generated query

```
findOne using query: { "isValid" : false , "isParent" : true , "clientId" : "CAQ123999" , "_class" : { "$in" : [ "com.test.cfp.model.TFSModel"]}} in db.collection: returns.tfs;
```

Obviously the _class  has the different package than the one in the mongo collection. How can I tell mongo to build a query without _class. I tried withIgnoredPaths and its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoExampleMapper` inspects the probe type and writes type restrictions according to known types in `MappingContext`. Types assignable to the probe get included in the `$in` operator.

```java
class One {
    @Id String id;
    String value;
    // ... 
}

class Two extends One {
    // ...
}

One probe = new One();
probe.value = "firefight";

Example<One> example = Example.of(probe, ExampleMatcher.matchingAny());
```

```
{
    value: firefight,
    _class: { $in : [ "com.example.One" , "com.example.Two" ] }
}
```

This behavior cannot be altered by using `.withIgnorePaths()` as the `_class` specifier is not part of the domain model. Please file an issue in [jira.spring.io](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO/) if you think this should be considered.

Looking at the provided sample data from the mongo collection you provided the `_class` attribute is not matching your domain type and therfore cannot be loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph Strobl . I ended up using MongoTemplate. I'm not sure whether it is valid scenario or not. Anyway I'll try to log this in jira.spring.io.